# Setter method based on user input

Tags: objective-c, scanf, getter-setter

New to Objective-C and trying to complete a final project for a class. I have created a method to set a date based on user input and am running into some trouble with the setter. User will first have to select option to add new entry and then program should ask user to enter a date and set date based on that input.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Planner : NSObject {

NSNumber *date;    
}

-(void) setDate:(NSNumber *)newDate;
-(NSNumber *) date;

@end

@implementation Planner

-(void) setDate:(NSNumber *) newDate
{
date = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: newDate];
NSLog(@"Enter date");
scanf("%i", newDate);
}

-(NSNumber *) date;
{
return date;
}

@end


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

int userAction;

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
Planner *newPlanner = [[Planner alloc] init];



NSLog(@"Please enter 1 to add a new entry and 2 to update an existing entry");
scanf("%i", userAction);

if (userAction == 1) {
    [newPlanner setDate];
}

else
    NSLog(@"will update");




[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) setDate:(NSNumber *) newDate;
```

`setDate` is supposed to receive an argument of type `NSNumber*`. But you are calling the method with out passing any parameter.

```
 [newPlanner setDate]; //  [newPlanner setDate: shouldPassNSNumberArgument];
```

Like -

```
[newPlanner setDate:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] ];
```